# AccessViolationException from c# when calling a function defined in a c++ library

Tags: c#, c++, interop, access-violation

We have a C++ library where some methods are defined and exported and are being used by our .NET (V 3.5) application. In the c++ library, a function is defined as below

```
int DLLEXPORT RunAnalysis(long *time, long handle, int *Status)
{
// some code...
}
```

in .Net assembly

Declaration

```
[DllImport("wt3145.dll")]
private static extern int RunAnalysis(ref long Time, long Handle, ref int status);
```

Usage

```
// Some work..
 ErrorCode = RunAnalysis(Time, ref Handle, ref Status);
// Some other work
```

every time this call is encountered an AccesViolationException occures. it gets solved only when i pass the second parameter with `ref` keyword although it is not being passed using a pointer.

Any specific reason for this behavior???

Comment: You have to declare the correct calling convention since the default for C++ is different then the one for C#.

Comment: Already tried all the calling conventions on it. no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
[DllImport("wt3145.dll")]
private static extern int RunAnalysis(ref int Time, int Handle, ref int status);
```

`long` in C++ is not the same as `long` in C#.

Comment: BTW what should i do when the values for `Time` and `Handle` go beyond limits of `int`. in our project It is a common scenario to have values for `Handle` go beyond the limits of `int`

Comment: than in C++ you should use `long long`, and in C# - `long`.